# Concatenate string in a loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am newbie to XSLT and fighting to get the right syntax for concatinating string in for-each loop. I have two variables declared depending on the condition need to concatenate a string to the variable.

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://p2p.wrox.com/xslt/79714-recursive-loop-concatenate-values.html) might help.

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide: 1. The source XML document (as small as possible). 2. The exact wanted result. 3. Any necessary rules for the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demonstration of string concatenation with an `xsl:for-each` and based on the value of a variable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vOddEven" select="1"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:for-each select="num[. mod 2 = $vOddEven]">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

`the wanted result (concatenation of all numbers that have the same "oddness" as the variable`$vOddEven`) is produced`:

```
0103050709
```